# DI Unity Container: вопрсо по Resolve

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

В файл UnityConfig.cs я добавляю запись:

```
сontainer.RegisterInstance<IRetryPolicyFactory>(new RetryPolicyfactory());
```

У меня есть класс **A()**, в котором есть свойство класса с типом **RetryPolicyfactory**

Вопрос: как из контейнера достать **RetryPolicyfactory** и присвоить в то свойство?

Не могу понять как это сделать, ведь должно быт ькак-то просто :(

Comment: Property injection https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/designtechniques/property-injection-in-c.html

Comment: Спасибо! Я понял как оно работает :)

Comment: А я бы сделал через конструктор, так было бы нагляднее.